# inner-join in MYSQL with UPDATE not working

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

The syntax doesn't work and returns error #1064 error on @rt:= ... 
I don't know where to place the variable so that it works.

```
UPDATE table 
@rt:=@rt+quantity;
INNER JOIN (SELECT @rt:=0) AS init ON 1=1
SET status='1'
WHERE price<10
AND @rt<=22
```

A working table with SELECT 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f125c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
UPDATE `table`
    SET status = '1'
    WHERE price < 10
    limit 22;
```

You don't need the variable to limit the number of rows.  This will update 22 rows where the price meets the condition in the `where` clause.  That is my best guess as to what you want to do.

EDIT:

Oh, you are trying to get the *sum* of the quantity.  Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
UPDATE `table` cross join
       (SELECT @rt := 0) vars
    SET status = if((@rt := @rt + quantity) <= 22, '1', status)
    WHERE price < 10;
```

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ca5d/1).

Comment: thanks for your response but that doesn't work for that - @rt specifies the quantity in a row  the table looks like price / quantity / status I've added a SQL fiddle

Comment: @tttddfd . . . `table` is a really bad name for a table.  You need to put it in back ticks.

Comment: ok it worked ... However, it has marked any price below 10 status 1 so even if the quantity in total @rt is over 22 in total

Comment: @tttddfd . . . I was thinking that might happen.  The `where` clause is evaluated before the `set`, so the incrementing doesn't affect the filtering.  That is fixed by changing the condition in the `set` clause.

Comment: it still marks everything with 1 --> only the status at price 9 and 9.1 should be updated to one, maybe it is not possible at all SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64b2d4/1

Comment: @tttddfd . . . Parentheses issue.